# batch file to delete all .wavs over 3 seconds in length

Tags: windows, batch-file, audio

I am creating a .bat to delete all .wav's in directory over 3 seconds in length, I found [this question that can be used to delete all .mp3's / .wav's under 3 seconds using MediaInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338992/windows-batch-file-to-delete-audio-files-with-length-requirement), how would you change it to delete files greater than 3 seconds v.s. less than 3 seconds? You have to remove 'echo' for it to execute

```
  @echo off
set "exe=MediaInfo.exe"
for /r %%a in (*.wav) do (
"%exe%" -f "%%a" | find "Duration" | findstr /r "00:00:0[210]" >nul && echo del "%%a"
)
pause
```

Run media info with a single file Output:

```
Duration                                 : 203
Duration                                 : 203ms
Duration                                 : 203ms
Duration                                 : 203ms
Duration                                 : 00:00:00.203
Duration                                 : 00:00:00.203
Duration                                 : 203
Duration                                 : 203ms
Duration                                 : 203ms
Duration                                 : 203ms
Duration                                 : 00:00:00.203
Duration                                 : 00:00:00.203
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Theese are files under 00:00:0[210], but I would like to target ones over 00:00:0[210]

Comment: The `>` is a redirect command, so I'm not surprised that didn't work. I don't have any audio files under 3 seconds on my computer, but I imagine you could simply add a `/v` to the `findstr` command.

Comment: Capture the media info output inside a a `FOR /F` command so that you can parse out the time elements.

Comment: @Squashman Hey Squash, thanks for the reply, I am not very experienced with batch programming, I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I don't have Media Info or any audio files to test with.  You will have to show us the output of Media info.  Please update your question with that info.

Comment: @Squashman Hey Squash, I updated with output

Comment: Well you updated your question but not with the information I asked for.  Do I need to clarify my request?

Comment: @Squashman I am unsure how I would summon the output of mediainfo, is there a command I could enter to do that?

Comment: Run media info with a single file.

Comment: @Squashman hey squash I updated with output from single file, it was very long

Comment: Well we only needed to see the duration output, so you could have just posted that or piped it to find like your original code was doing.

Comment: @Squashman I updated it with the pipe for duration only, thanks!

Comment: for getting duration in milliseconds: `mediainfo "--Output=General;%Duration%" %%F`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does not take into account the milliseconds and assumes the last duration time output will be in this format 00:00:00.123

```
@echo off

for /r %%F in (*.wav) do (
    FOR /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=:. " %%G IN ('mediainfo.exe -f "%%F" ^| find "Duration"') DO (
        set "ftime=%%G%%H%%I"
    )
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    IF "!ftime!" GTR "000003" DEL "%%F"
    endlocal
)
pause
```

Comment: thanks for your all your help! I made a few changes and it works! I just capitilized the M and I in MediaInfo.exe and change all the %%F's to %%a's and it worked

Comment: @Jeff Sorry about the mix up on the for variable.  File names are not case sensitive in Windows so that does not matter.

Comment: sweet I wasn't sure if it mattered but I did that just incase, good to know for future, but it must of been the %%F to %%a (variable). Thanks Again!

Comment: @Jeff I always like to start my FOR variables with the letter G.  There is certain caveats when it comes to using the FOR modifiers that can give you some goofy output if you use a letter that is a modifier.

Comment: I see, windows command prompt / batch coding is very new to me, I have more PHP / Jquery expeirence mostly, this stuff really comes in handy though, it saves alot of time and makes things so much easier. Looking forward to continue learning it